# Can a google apps script be written to filter emails based on dynamic duplicate content within those emails?

Tags: google-apps-script, filter, gmail

I would like to find out if this is possible, so I can then look for help to actually implement this. The problem:

I get order notification email sent by e-commerce store platform. All the products are subscriptions, and repeat periodically, however, the notification email looks identical whether it's a first order, or any following subscription order. I really don't need to see any of those followup emails, and only need the first time order one.

The filter that I envision would check if a specific line containing customer first and last name is a duplicate of an email that already exists in the inbox in that exact word order. The problem is, that customer names cannot be anticipated. So I need to:

1. check if the line "BILLED TO: First Last name" has a duplicate among the earlier received emails;
2. mark the email as read if it finds a duplicate; do nothing if it's a first occurrence.

Is that possible at all? If someone has a starter code suggestion or some template to work off, I'd love to give it a try and see if I can figure out the setup, or hire someone to write it for me if I can't unravel this.

Thank you all for your input!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have 2 questions. 1. If you want to achieve your goal using `google-apps-script`, how do you want to run the script? For example, do you want to directly run the script with the script editor? 2. Which is your email body of `check if the line "BILLED TO: First Last name" has a duplicate among the earlier received emails;` text body or HTML body? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: It is probably possible.

Comment: @Tanaike, the "Billed to: " is part of an HTML body. Regarding running the script, I'm only familiar with running it through the script editor. Thanks for pondering on this!

Answer (score 0):

### SUGGESTION

It is possible to check for duplicate emails and mark them as read, to ensure that only the new orders are left unread or untouched. For this case, there are some things that you need to take note of:

1. The script that I used takes into account the ***email subject header*** to determine if it is a unique email or a duplicate. You can use this as your baseline if ever the sentence that you are checking, the `BILLED TO:` line is located elsewhere in the email.
2. I used the `GmailApp.getInboxThreads()` function to get the emails from my inbox, which are then checked individually if there are any duplicate emails among them. Do take note that from the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getinboxthreadsstart,-max), it states there:

> This call will fail when the size of all threads is too large for the system to handle. Where the thread size is unknown, and potentially very large, please use the 'paged' call, and specify ranges of the threads to retrieve in each call.

Hence, if a large amount of emails will be scanned, it may not be able to handle such.

3. Again, the script provided will mark all duplicate emails (that satisfies the given condition of having the "BILLED TO:" line) as read, and will leave any unique emails untouched, as per your specifications.

You can check out this sample script for your reference:

```
function readDuplicate() {
  var messages = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 5);  // gets the 1st 5 emails on your inbox
  var regex = /Billed to:/i;                      // the sentence that will be used as a filter for the email subjects
  for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    // this checks if the current email's subject on the loop contains
    // the "Billed to: " phrase on the sentence, so that it can be checked
    // if it's unique or not
    if (regex.exec(messages[i].getFirstMessageSubject())) {
      // stores the email subject as a buffer/comparator
      var strComp = messages[i].getFirstMessageSubject();
      // this loop checks if the saved email subject is a duplicate of other emails
      // and will be marked as read if true
      for (j = i; j < messages.length - i; j++) {
        if (messages[j + 1].getFirstMessageSubject() == strComp) {
          GmailApp.markThreadRead(messages[i]);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### OUTPUT

This is what it should look like after running the script: [image]

### REFERENCES

- [GmailApp.getInboxThreads()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getinboxthreadsstart,-max)
- [GmailApp.markThreadRead()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#markthreadreadthread)
- [RegExp exec()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp)

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you! I'll have to try it out and probably tweak since it seems to mark the first original as read too, however, it should only mark the duplicate as read only if the "original" is read. If both are undread, then both should stay. This gives me a fantastic headstart. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this, @Mic Test

Comment: You're welcome! And thanks for letting me know of the additional behavior that you are looking for with the duplicate emails and its "parent" or "original" email. For that, there should be some things that can be tweaked inside the "if" statement on the second "for" loop to check if the original email is read or unread, to see which is to be applied to the duplicates.

Comment: In any case, feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) or leave an upvote so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that this can be used as a reference or guide to work on.